# Traveling on a nearly expired passport

Tags: passports, turkey

Several months ago, I left my home country to work abroad. At the time of departure, I had > 6 months remaining on my passport, but now I have only about 2 remaining.

I want to take a brief trip outside of the schengen zone (where I've been working and have a valid work permit), to Turkey.

Am I likely to encounter problems traveling in this way?

I gather that normally one should not travel on a passport that has < 6 months remaining before expiration, but I had >6 months when I left my home country, and intend to return prior to expiration (i.e. all of my travel will occur with a valid passport).

Comment: Why not just renew your passport?

Comment: @Karlson Renewing a Canadian passport while abroad is a 3-6 week process, during which the passport will be taken away. No way to expedite short of flying back to Canada and doing it in person, according to the embassy here.  Additionally I would need to replace my work permits and various other items in the current passport.

Comment: You will need to do it in 2 months anyway.

Comment: @Karlson True, but the trip would be sooner than 3-6 weeks. It's also much easier to apply in person.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this rule of >6 months depends on the visited country, your citizenship and the type of visa.

There is a [TripAdivsor forum](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293969-i367-k5505894-Passport_validity-Turkey.html)  saying you need to have your `passport valid for 90 days after your visa expiry date`.

This means you most likely need to have your passport valid for >6 months in the case of Turkey (If you just travel). You can find information related to your specific country directly from [Turkish Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa)

Comment: Thanks. Bothersome. Guess I'm out a grand. Let this be a lesson to those buying non-refundable tickets: Check your passport and entry requirements first, not a week before the trip!